# Data Abstraction Layer between tastypie and Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm, tastypie

I have been entrusted with creating an API for a large existing codebase and have decided to use tasypie. The problem is with the app structure.

We have a database on top of which the Djnago ORM runs. The app doesn't work directly with the ORM though but through a set of methods (the Data Abstraction Layer) which handle things like creating the ORM objects, validating them etc.

I would like to hook up tastypie to said methods to get all the benefits of throttling, authentication etc. but I have no idea how to do that.

I've attempted to write a custom data source for tastypie (like the riak example they have in the docs) but I'm thoroughly confused as to what I need to override and what each method does.

So, to sum up:

1. How would I go about adding a Data Abstraction Layer between tastypie and the ORM?
2. Is using a custom data source the right way?
3. How would I go about creating such a custom data source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, TasyPie does that. Basically its really simple to hook up your API calls directly to your django ORM functionality. You'd use classes related to your Django models that are subclasses of TasyPie's ModelResource, and ithandles things so they work fast out of the box.
But for people that want to do something more customized like interface with your Data Abstarction Layer there's a way to customize things. Basically instead of using ModelResource you use Resource classes instead and you have a set of methods that you have to implement to make them work with your Data Abstarction Layer when different API calls are made
Its described in the docs here:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html

There is one example given in the docs for how to implement custom Resources described under a section called

Using Tastypie With Non-ORM Data Sources
( I'd post the link but Stack Overflow limits me to po

Its not really spelled out exactly what the code is doing unfortunately and the explaination is a little thin IMHO
This example is making a custom interface to a completely non ORM No SQL database called Riak. Its great if you are using Riak, or even if you know something about Riak, which I don't. I found it a little confusing trying to read code about two new technologies and figuring what the code was actually doing.

There's a nice simpler example of using a custom Resource here made for educational purposes that connects the API calls to simple python classes  :

https://gist.github.com/nomadjourney/794424

I am not an expert on Tastypie at all in fact I just started with it.
Like yourself I need to implement a custom Resource instead of using the Easy out of the box ModelResources.
I have not been able to do it successfully yet, but I thought I'd let you know what I've found. 
In the TastyPie docs they mention the folks who wrote it maintain an active IRC channel where they will help you. If you're still stuck this might be better than stackoverflow if you don't get what you need here.
Good luck,
I'll try to post an example if I get one working
best Doug

Answer (score 0):

Another resource that is slightly easier to understand than TastyPie's non-ORM example:
http://thehungrycoder.com/python/using-non-orm-data-sources-with-tastypie-in-django.html

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this more and have found the clearest way to understand what the Resource methods do is by looking at the actual TastyPie source code for Resource and ModelResource:
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py

This shows how it works in the case of using django's ORM
and it has some decent inline documentation that explains it.

Its not always immediately obvious what's going on even with this documentation but what I did is make a REsource subclass starting out as identical to ModelResource, then add logging to each method and manipulate the API to see what methods are called and what they do.
Then I'm going to slowly, step by step change the methods to implement my custom, non ORM behavior.